# php success message handling

Tags: php, forms, redirect, get

I've a form i slideDown with Jquery, and a php script in which i need  to redirect after sendind data to server (php),and also showing a "success" message (not in the url but in the form).
I'm doing it this way (as i found here in stackoverflow):

```
header("location:VIP.php?response=1");
```

and and in VIP.php right after :

```
if (isset ($_GET['response']))
{
    if ($_GET['response']=="1")
    {
      echo "Se ha registrado con éxito"; //this is my success message (spanish)
    }
}
```

it works like a charm, the only thing is thay i need to  style this, it shows at the top left of the body ... and i don't know how to make it  show in the form (or any other specific div)

If anyone can enlight me, i'd much appreciate it.Thanks!

Comment: Want to show us your form? Want to tell us more about the interaction between jQuery and PHP?

Comment: move the location of the php code block, to wherever in your page structure you DO want the message output.

Answer (score 1):

Do it like this:

```
if (isset ($_GET['response']))
{
   if ($_GET['response']=="1")
   {
       $msg = "Se ha registrado con éxito"; //this is my success message (spanish)
   }
}
```

and then somewhere in your html page (e.g. in your form):

```
<?php if( $msg ): ?><div class="notice"><?php echo $msg ?></div><?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: don't forget to initialize $msg outside the if() structure, otherwise you'll just be causing an undefined variable warning if the msg ISN'T set.

Comment: In fact, the complete solution should be along the lines of `<?php if( $msg ): ?><div class="notice"><?php echo $msg ?></div><?php endif; ?>`